# Android Spinner crash when the textView is first

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm using a spinner and text view near it  when the text View is in the right side the work properly but when I switch them the app crash in the line below in the java class

`spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner)`
my xml code is

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="30" />
</LinearLayout>
```

now when I put the spinner first its work fine

Comment: It isn't enough to post the line on which the error occurs...post the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

project -> Clean your project,

it is just because your R.java cannot be refreshed. So when you changed the order of widget, compiler wait textview first but there are spinner so you get classCastException.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast
>   to android.widget.Spinner

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's your problem, but your should set your android:layout_width to 0dp for your TextView and Spinner.